# Logout is not destroying the session

Tags: php, mysql

My logout page is not destoying the session. I have searched and read about same issue but none of them solved my problem.

Below is my logout page. Note that I have two blocks of php because I have a template in between.

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
  session_start();
  $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
?>
<?php
  if($username && $userid) {
    session_destroy();
    echo "You have been logged out.<a href='members.only.php'>My Logs.</a>";
  }
  else
    echo "You are not logged in.";
?>
```

As one can see after I logout I have a link to  a members restriced page so I can check. But it still welcomes the last user that was logged in.

Comment: It doesn't give you any error? use ini_set('display_errors', 'On')

Comment: Did you get ""You are not logged in." message?

Answer (score 4):

Please read documentation of [session_destroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php):

`session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called.`

That means, you should do something else. For example:

`$_SESSION = array();`

Answer (score 2):

session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called. You can read more about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Answer (score 1):

Replace session_destroy part with this:

```
   <?php
      if($username && $userid) {

    // If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
    // Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
        $params = session_get_cookie_params();
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
            $params["path"], $params["domain"],
            $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
        );
    }

    // Finally, destroy the session.
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION = array();
        echo "You have been logged out.<a href='members.only.php'>My Logs.</a>";
      }
      else
        echo "You are not logged in.";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
session_cache_limiter ('private_no_expire, must-revalidate');
```